# How can I load additional properties file in a spring boot application packaged as a war?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, war

I have a standard springboot web app. I want to load properties file that's not in the classpath. application.properties is in the classpath and is being read correctly.

I don't have an issue when I'm building a jar. I just put the .properties alongside the jar and it works. But when I package a war, I couldn't get the application to read the properties file .

Answer (score 0):

You put the properties file parallel to application.properties file and load it in a class like this:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:foo.properties")
public class My class {

@Value( "${some.property}" )
String myProp;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can using `ClassPathResource`. given Class for loading resources.

This is sample code for you

```
ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("/application/context/blabla.yml");
InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
File file = resource.getFile();

// using inputStream or file
```

[ClassPathResource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring `application.properties` to have spring profiles and use the spring profiles to define separate properties for each environment as you like.You can even separate out the spring profiles in to different files like `appication-dev.properties` etc  so that you can have each spring profile in different files.

You can read the properties by using @Configuration annotation :

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(TestProperties.class)
public class MySampleConfiguration {
}
```

Here TestProperties.class is used to map the values from the property file or yaml .
Reference in detail : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html